# Are SSL Certificates (Private and Public key) generated by OpenSSL and makecert compatible?

Tags: encryption, tls, openssl

Are RSA SSL Certificates (Private and Public key) generated by makecert compatible with OpenSSL decryption ie. can I decrypt them with the openssl_* methods? I am working on two-way SSL authentication between a .NET client and a PHP service, so I want to know if I have to create OpenSSL certificates on the .NET side.

Comment: Which kind of certificates: RSA, DSA, DH?

Comment: RSA certificates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both makecert and OpenSSL follow [X.509](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509), so they are compatible -- in theory. X.509 is extensible is various arbitrary ways, and has been extended in various arbitrary and exotic ways, so anything can happen.

Practically, OpenSSL powers a lot of existing HTTPS web sites (according to [these statistics](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2012/01/03/january-2012-web-server-survey.html), [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) powers more than 50% of all Web sites, and when Apache does HTTPS, it does so with OpenSSL(*)) so chances are that Microsoft tried not to break compatibility in that matter. In my experience, .NET and OpenSSL talke to each other quite politely.

(*) Well, Apache can also use [GnuTLS](http://modgnutls.sourceforge.net/), but it seems to be rather uncommon.